# Docker private registry login using htpasswd file doesn't work

Tags: docker, security, passwords, docker-registry, .htpasswd

I am adding authentication to my docker private registry in windows 10. I have initially not implemented basic authentication but later, I implemented it using a htpasswd file which is in my auth folder. I have been following up on the instructions given in this tutorial: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1263831/How-to-secure-your-private-Docker-Registry . But because windows was having issues with the htpasswd file hence, I had to create a htpasswd file using HtPasswd generator and copied it to my auth folder.

Later, I ran this command to build a container and binding volume, port and htpasswd file from host to my container:
`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name hub.local -v C:\localHub\registry:/var/lib/registry -v C:\localHub\auth:/auth -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/.htpasswd -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000 registry:2`

It works fine, and I can see the container is up and running on port 5000:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                    NAMES
41499c3f07e6        registry:2                    "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes             0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   hub.local
```

but when I try to login into my container using `docker login 172.16.13.38:5000` it asks me for username and password but shows the same error.

```
docker login 172.16.13.38:5000
Username: muskan
Password:
Error response from daemon: login attempt to http://172.16.13.38:5000/v2/ failed with status: 401 Unauthorized
```

I have double checked that the htpasswd file is there in the container's auth folder and my registry is up at http://172.16.13.38:5000/v2/_catalog

Kindly help me with this. I am not able to figure it out and have been trying since last two days.

htpasswd file has this content:

`muskan:$apr1$k9......$4fyyuas7/VfnuBnPRbFI//`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you solved the issue?

Comment: can you tell more about what you did please, the accepted answer holds nothing new since your container was already up and running. I tried the REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED: 'true from the accepted answer and it gives errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
docker run --entrypoint htpasswd httpd:2 -Bbn USERNAM_HERE PASSWORD_HERE > PATH_TOVOLUME/htpasswd
```

After you have the htpasswd file, you point to its location

Example here is use docker-compose

```
      REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/htpasswd
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry Realm
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED: 'true
```

Answer (score 12):

you have to use bcrypt, so for the creation of htpasswd file use :

```
$ htpasswd -cB htpasswd someUsername
```

Comment: Thanks, Mohashan, your answer helped me resolve the issue.